# Find missing numbers sequence in multiple column - excel

Tags: vb.net, excel

I use this VB script to detect missing sequence number in excel

```
Sub Missingvalues()
Dim rng As Range
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim StartV As Single, EndV As Single, i As Single, j As Single
Dim k() As Single
Dim WS As Worksheet
ReDim k(0)
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Select a range:", _
Title:="Extract missing values", _
Default:=Selection.Address, Type:=8)
StartV = InputBox("Start value:")
EndV = InputBox("End value:")
On Error GoTo 0
Set WS = Sheets.Add
WS.Range("a:a,c:c,e:e" & rng.Rows.CountLarge).Value = rng.Value
With WS.Sort
    .SortFields.Add Key:=WS.Range("a1,c1,e1"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    .SetRange Range("a:a,c:c,e:e" & rng.Rows.CountLarge)
    .Header = xlNo
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
Set rng1 = WS.Range("a1:a,c1:c,e1:e" & rng.Rows.CountLarge)
For i = StartV To EndV
    On Error Resume Next
    j = Application.Match(i, rng1)
    If Err = 0 Then
        If rng1(j, 1) <> i Then
            k(UBound(k)) = i
            ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) + 1)
        End If
    Else
        k(UBound(k)) = i
        ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) + 1)
    End If
    On Error GoTo 0
Next i
ReDim Preserve k(UBound(k) - 1)
WS.Range("b1,d1,f1") = "Missing values"
WS.Range("b2:b,d2:2,f2:f" & UBound(k) + 1) = Application.Transpose(k)
End Sub
```

But this code works only for *one column*. I want for multiple column like this:

http://imageshack.com/a/img834/9378/6w7s2.jpg

Is there a solution?

Comment: Instead of using ranges "A1:A" use the ranges for the columns you want

Comment: i want multiple range on different column, for example A1:A, C1:C, E1:E etc - How can i edit the code?

Comment: First, what do you mean by A1:A range? did you meant A:A? Second, you can select a rage with skipped columns like Range("a:a,c:c,e:e").

Comment: You should not write `Next i`, remove the "i" here. You should also not use `goto`, that might be what causes it to fail. At the beginning, you can do : `Dim k(0) As Single`; no need to `ReDim` 2 lines after. *Wabonano*'s comment covers the rest. Also, don't declare loop counters (`i` in that case), VB handles it properly.

Comment: i try to edit the range but error is `Run-Time Error '1004' Method 'Range of object_'worksheet' failed` Please look my edited code above. What is wrong, i don't understand how edit if i have 3 column **a**,**c**,**e**? Can u paste on pastebin to help me, please?